# Google Places how to autocomplete and componentRestrictions search only from a specific country?

Tags: node.js, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

I want that when user types in my autocomplete search, that the data comes from Google servers will be related only to a specific country.

I am calling to their webservice via API in Node.js like this:

```
var headers = {
  'User-Agent':       'Super Agent/0.0.1',
  'Content-Type':     'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
};
// Configure the request
var options = {
  url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json",
  method: 'POST',
  headers: headers,
  qs: {
    key: gkey,
    input: input,
    types: ['(cities)'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'il'}
  }
};
// Start the request
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  // returning the body to the frontend
});
```

Note that I have tried to play with this but nothing works.
I can able to see worldwide results.

I have tried to search about this but nothing solved this.

Comment: Autocomplete web service is supposed to be GET, not POST. Have you tried with GET? You can also have a look at NodeJs client library for web services: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js

Comment: Yes I have just tried with GET and it worked just fine.
You better answer it, so others that face this issue will read this later and see the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Maps API web services supposed to be used with GET method, not the POST method. The only web service that supposed to be used with POST is [Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro).

You should change the code to

```
var headers = {
  'User-Agent':       'Super Agent/0.0.1',
  'Content-Type':     'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
};
// Configure the request
var options = {
  url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json",
  method: 'GET',
  headers: headers,
  qs: {
    key: gkey,
    input: input,
    types: ['(cities)'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'IL'}
  }
};
// Start the request
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  // returning the body to the frontend
});
```

I hope this helps!